# android how to run in background my application on startup

Tags: android, startup, background-process

I am a bit of an android noob and I am not sure how can I run my app as long as the phone is on.
Well I don't sure how can I open my app on startup and make it so it will run in the background.
By the way, my app is notifing me when I have a certain amount of battery power left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn Android Service and then implement battery application.
First read android life cycle and its basics then you should try application developent
use this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)